# Include the Matheron estimator in pykrige

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, geostatistics

Hi I have another question: how can I include the Matheron estimator in my program and still use Pykrige?

My program looks like this:

```
from pykrige.ok import OrdinaryKriging
from pykrige.kriging_tools import write_asc_grid
import pykrige.kriging_tools as kt

x = np.array([-100, 280, -290, 23, 101, 110])
y = np.array([54, 100, 590, 470, 200, 25])
z = np.array([29.3, 21.0, 19.2, 29.1, 21.9, 23.1])

Ok = OrdinaryKriging(
    x,
    y,
    z,
    variogram_model='exponential ',
    verbose= True,
    enable_plotting= True
)

gridx =np.arange(-300, 300, 10, dtype='float64')
gridy =np.arange(0,600, 10, dtype='float64')
zstar, ss = Ok.execute("grid", gridx, gridy)

cax = plt.imshow(zstar, extent=(-300, 300, 0, 600), origin='lower')
plt.scatter(x, y, c=z, marker=".")
cbar = plt.colorbar(cax)
plt.title('Test Interpolation')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sebastian here from the [GeoStat-Framework](https://github.com/GeoStat-Framework). The Matheron estimator for the empirical variogram is used by default in PyKrige (and is the only option).

Since PyKrige and [GSTools](https://github.com/GeoStat-Framework/GSTools) are working well together, you could use GSTools for the variogram analysis part, where you can also choose the `"cressie"` estimator (or `"matheron"` by default as well):

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from pykrige.ok import OrdinaryKriging
import gstools as gs
import numpy as np

x = np.array([-100, 280, -290, 23, 101, 110])
y = np.array([54, 100, 590, 470, 200, 25])
z = np.array([29.3, 21.0, 19.2, 29.1, 21.9, 23.1])

model = gs.Exponential(dim=2)
bin_center, gamma = gs.vario_estimate(
    pos=[x, y],
    field=z,
    bin_edges=range(0, 900, 150),
    estimator="cressie",
)
model.fit_variogram(bin_center, gamma)
ax = model.plot(x_max=max(bin_center))
ax.scatter(bin_center, gamma)

Ok = OrdinaryKriging(
    x,
    y,
    z,
    variogram_model=model,
    verbose=True,
    enable_plotting=True
)

gridx =np.arange(-300, 300, 10, dtype='float64')
gridy =np.arange(0,600, 10, dtype='float64')
zstar, ss = Ok.execute("grid", gridx, gridy)

cax = plt.imshow(zstar, extent=(-300, 300, 0, 600), origin='lower')
plt.scatter(x, y, c=z, marker=".")
cbar = plt.colorbar(cax)
plt.title('Test Interpolation')
plt.show()
```

The estimation in PyKrige has some slightly different assumptions (like a set number of lags), but in GSTools you have more fine control.

Hope this helps.

Cheers, Sebastian

Comment: Hi Sebastian, thanks for your answer I have another question about Pykrige and hope you can answer it for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72574394/advance-a-basemap-plot

Comment: hi I want to plot Isotopic data which are dependend from height. So I would use more likly universal kriging. However I wounder If I schould use for this propose 3D UK or normal UK? and which drift  function would you recomend for Interpolating precipitation data?

Comment: 3D UK is for 3D data (e.g. depending on lat-lon-altitude). But I guess precipitation is mostly only given for lat-lon coordinates. We often use the DEM as an external drift (called specified drift in PyKrige and needs to  be provided at the output grid as well).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However in fact, the isotope data depends on the altitude, so 3DUK seems to be a good choice, doesn't it? Or should I just take the UK and use the altitude as a driver?

Comment: You mean as a "drift"? You could try that ;-)

Comment: Since I have not been programming for very long, I would like to know if there is an example somewhere that explains how the drift is composed! and yes I mean drift ;)

Comment: Here is an example with specified drift (3 drifts, you only want 1) in 3D:
https://geostat-framework.readthedocs.io/projects/pykrige/en/stable/examples/02_kriging3D.html#sphx-glr-examples-02-kriging3d-py

Comment: That means: k3d3, ss3d = uk3d.execute(
    "grid", gridx, gridy, gridz, specified_drift_arrays=[ zg] or?

Comment: maby can this be right? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72627986/plotting-3d-data-in-2d-map (but all in all thanks for your patience:))

Comment: Hi @greeeeeeen do you know if there have ever been errors when trying to display UK3D in Basemap as a 2D image?

Comment: hi, sry that I ask you so often, hovever I think you are the only one who can help me in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72631305/advance-a-interpolation I would be very happy if you could have a look at this :) All the best