# Advance a Basemap Plot

Tags: python, numpy, mapping, matplotlib-basemap

First: sorry for the long Question

Hi I would like to interpolate a map and do this with the package `Pykrige`. For this I create the Meshgrid:

```
def get_data(df):
    return {
        "lons": df['Longitude'],
        "lats": df['Latitude'],
        "values": df['O18'],
        "alts": df['Altitude'],
    }

def extend_data(data):
    return {
        "lons": np.concatenate([np.array([lon-360 for lon in data["lons"]]), data["lons"], np.array([lon+360 for lon in data["lons"]])]),
        "lats":  np.concatenate([data["lats"], data["lats"], data["lats"]]),
        "values":  np.concatenate([data["values"], data["values"], data["values"]]),
        "alts": np.concatenate([data["alts"], data["alts"], data["alts"]]),
    }

def generate_grid(data, basemap, delta=1):
    grid = {
        'lon': np.arange(-180, 180, delta),
        'lat': np.arange(np.amin(data["lats"]), np.amax(data["lats"]), delta) # dont extrapolate towards the poles
    }
    grid["x"], grid["y"] = np.meshgrid(grid["lon"], grid["lat"])
    grid["x"], grid["y"] = basemap(grid["x"], grid["y"])
    return grid
```

The interpolation then looks like this:

```
def interpolate(data, grid):
    UK = UniversalKriging(
        data["lons"],
        data["lats"],
        data["values"],
        variogram_model='exponential',
        specified_drift = data["alts"], 
        # nlags=100, 
    )
    return UK.execute("grid", grid["lon"], grid["lat"])
```

With the command I plot the interpolated data in a map and use `contourf`.

```
def plot_mesh_data(interpolation, grid, basemap):
    colormesh = basemap.contourf(grid["x"], grid["y"],  interpolation,100, cmap='jet', ) #plot the data on the map. plt.cm.RdYlBu_r
    color_bar = basemap.colorbar(colormesh,location='bottom',pad="10%")
```

However, the result for Europe is very disappointing. (White Dots: Messuring Stations)
[image]
How can I improve the code so that the representation looks even more detailed? Just as a note, the colour range is already very fine-tuned and unfortunately cannot be used for this.

As you can see, there are many stations in Europe, all with different values. Therefore, the Contourf plot should be much more accurate. For example, I can give this example: https://images.app.goo.gl/sPTMM6xe5Wj5QtGN8
You can see that the level boundaries are shown with much more detail than in my example, even though there is the same amount of data.

Furthermore, I wonder how the interpolation in Antarctica can be weighted so that it has a higher impact on the Antarctic region (marked).
[image]

and third, I am trying to mask Greenland and have the code:

```
def mask_greenland(axes, basemap):
    #r = shapefile.Reader(r"C:/Users/Oliver Weisser/Desktop/Bachelor/Programm/borders/Greenland/GRL_adm0.shp")
    basemap.readshapefile('C:/Users/Oliver Weisser/Desktop/Bachelor/Programm/borders/Greenland/GRL_adm0', 'greenland', drawbounds = False)
    patches   = []
    for info, shape in zip(basemap.greenland_info, basemap.greendland):
        if info['nombre'] == 'Selva':
            patches.append( Polygon(np.array(shape), True) )
            
    axes.add_collection(PatchCollection(patches, facecolor= 'm', edgecolor='k', linewidths=1., zorder=2))
```

I use this data:

https://geodata.lib.utexas.edu/catalog/stanford-sd368wz2435

However, basemap has relatively many errors like:

```
AttributeError: 'Basemap' object has no attribute 'greendland'
```

my data: https://filebin.net/n9mnzakasaf6tb0g

my code is:

```
from traceback import print_tb
import numpy as np
from pykrige.ok import OrdinaryKriging
from pykrige.kriging_tools import write_asc_grid
import pykrige.kriging_tools as kt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from matplotlib.patches import Path, PathPatch
import pandas as pd

def load_data():
    df = pd.read_csv(r"FileName")
    return(df)

def get_data(df):
    return {
        "lons": df['Longitude'],
        "lats": df['Latitude'],
        "values": df['O18a'],
    }

def extend_data(data):
    # Copy data to the "left" and "right" to allow for interpolation to the edges of the map
    return {
        "lons": np.concatenate([np.array([lon-360 for lon in data["lons"]]), data["lons"], np.array([lon+360 for lon in data["lons"]])]),
        "lats":  np.concatenate([data["lats"], data["lats"], data["lats"]]),
        "values":  np.concatenate([data["values"], data["values"], data["values"]]),
    }

def generate_grid(data, basemap, delta=1):
    grid = {
        'lon': np.arange(-180, 180, delta),
        'lat': np.arange(np.amin(data["lats"]), np.amax(data["lats"]), delta) # dont extrapolate towards the poles
    }
    grid["x"], grid["y"] = np.meshgrid(grid["lon"], grid["lat"])
    grid["x"], grid["y"] = basemap(grid["x"], grid["y"])
    return grid

def interpolate(data, grid):
    OK =OrdinaryKriging(
        data["lons"],
        data["lats"],
        data["values"],
        variogram_model='exponential',
        nlags=40, 
        pseudo_inv=True,
        weight=True,
        verbose=True,
    )
    return OK.execute("grid", grid["lon"], grid["lat"])

def prepare_map_plot():
    figure, axes = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
    basemap = Basemap(projection='robin', lon_0=0, lat_0=0, resolution='h',area_thresh=1000,ax=axes) 
    basemap.drawcoastlines() 
    basemap.drawparallels(np.arange(-90.,120.,30.))
    basemap.drawmeridians(np.arange(0.,420.,60.))
    return figure, axes, basemap

def plot_mesh_data(interpolation, grid, basemap):
    colormesh = basemap.contourf(grid["x"], grid["y"],  interpolation,32, cmap='RdBu_r', ) #plot the data on the map. plt.cm.RdYlBu_r
    color_bar = basemap.colorbar(colormesh,location='bottom',pad="10%") 
def mask_greenland(axes, basemap):
    #r = shapefile.Reader(r"C:/Users/Oliver Weisser/Desktop/Bachelor/Programm/borders/Greenland/GRL_adm0.shp")
    basemap.readshapefile('C:/Users/Oliver Weisser/Desktop/Bachelor/Programm/borders/Greenland/GRL_adm0', 'greenland', drawbounds = False)
    patches   = []
    for info, shape in zip(basemap.greenland_info, basemap.greendland):
        if info['nombre'] == 'Selva':
            patches.append( Polygon(np.array(shape), True) )
            
    axes.add_collection(PatchCollection(patches, facecolor= 'm', edgecolor='k', linewidths=1., zorder=2))

df = load_data()
base_data = get_data(df)
figure, axes, basemap = prepare_map_plot()
grid = generate_grid(base_data, basemap, 1)
extended_data = extend_data(base_data)
interpolation, interpolation_error = interpolate(extended_data, grid)
plot_mesh_data(interpolation, grid,basemap)
mask_greenland(axes, basemap)
plt.show()
```

Comment: can you elaborate on what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: @pask So hopefully it is more cleare now ;)

Comment: Can you provide some code that is reproducible without accessing your hard drive?

Comment: @norok2  sorry i Forget that

Comment: What package is providing `mpl_toolkits`? It seems that I cannot install it with `pip`

Comment: @norok2 basemap

Comment: I am unable to reproduce the code that is supposed to plot the map of Europe (looks like its missing the "main" code --- the functions are never called). However, I have had some success with the whole world map.

Comment: oh yeah I only zoomed in#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd assume you just have to decrease your delta used in `generate_grid`. This might also require you to select a smaller window to keep computation cost reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to specify the colour levels of [`matplotlib.pyplot.contourf()`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.contourf.html):

Below I adapted some [Contourf demo](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/contourf_demo.html) to show the effect of increasing the number of levels:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

origin = 'lower'

delta = 0.025

x = y = np.arange(-3.0, 3.01, delta)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)
Z1 = np.exp(-X**2 - Y**2)
Z2 = np.exp(-(X - 1)**2 - (Y - 1)**2)
Z = (Z1 - Z2) * 2

nr, nc = Z.shape

# put NaNs in one corner:
Z[-nr // 6:, -nc // 6:] = np.nan
# contourf will convert these to masked


Z = np.ma.array(Z)
# mask another corner:
Z[:nr // 6, :nc // 6] = np.ma.masked

# mask a circle in the middle:
interior = np.sqrt(X**2 + Y**2) < 0.5
Z[interior] = np.ma.masked

fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2, constrained_layout=True)

CS1 = axs[0].contourf(X, Y, Z, 10, cmap=plt.cm.jet, origin=origin)
CS2 = axs[1].contourf(X, Y, Z, 100, cmap=plt.cm.jet, origin=origin)
```

[image: plot]

where essentially I call `contourf()` with `levels=10` and `levels=100` in the last two lines.

---

More concretely for your code, you could replace this line:

```
colormesh = basemap.contourf(
    grid["x"], grid["y"], interpolation, 32, cmap='RdBu_r')
```

with something like:

```
colormesh = basemap.contourf(
    grid["x"], grid["y"], interpolation, 1000, cmap='RdBu_r')
```

or you want to specify the levels yourself as a NumPy array.

With 32 levels:

[image: 32_levels]

With 1000 levels:

[image: 1000_levels]

Comment: that looks nice, but in the example Link I posted you can clearly see the different levels

Comment: My question is, how can I achieve that the individual level boundaries are displayed with significantly more detail?

Comment: have you tried with `antialiased=False` or `nchunk=0` as options of `contourf()`?

Comment: ok i tried it but this didn´t realy work

Comment: @Weiss Are you sure the data has more details than you currently see?

Comment: yes, if you take another look at the section from eruopa, you can see the measuring stations and how rough the levels are (this doesn't get any better if you increase the levels).