# Advance a Interpolation

Tags: python, numpy, mapping, interpolation, kriging

Note; No special knowledge of Pykrige is needed to answer the question, as I already mention examples in the question!

---

Hi I would like to use Universal Kriging in my code. For this I have data that is structured as follows:

```
      Latitude   Longitude  Altitude          H2        O18        Date    Year  month       dates  a_diffO       O18a
0    45.320000  -75.670000     114.0  -77.500000 -11.110000  2004-09-15  2004.0    9.0  2004-09-15   -0.228 -10.882000
1    48.828100    9.200000     314.0  -31.350000  -4.880000  2004-09-15  2004.0    9.0  2004-09-15   -0.628  -4.252000
2    51.930000  -10.250000       9.0  -18.800000  -3.160000  2004-09-15  2004.0    9.0  2004-09-15   -0.018  -3.142000
3    48.248611   16.356389     198.0  -45.000000  -6.920000  2004-09-15  2004.0    9.0  2004-09-15   -0.396  -6.524000
4    50.338100    7.600000      85.0  -19.200000  -3.190000  2004-09-15  2004.0    9.0  2004-09-15   -0.170  -3.020000
```

You can find my data here:https://wetransfer.com/downloads/9c02e4fc1c2da765d5ee9137e6d7df4920220618071144/8f450e

I want to interpolate the data (Latitude, Longitude, Altitude and O18) with Universal Kriging and use the height as a drift function.

So far I have programmed this here but I am not getting anywhere, e.g. I don't know how to effectively use the height as a drift function and the information from the Pykrige documentation is of limited help:

```
from traceback import print_tb
from typing_extensions import Self
import numpy as np
from pykrige.uk import UniversalKriging
from pykrige.kriging_tools import write_asc_grid
import pykrige.kriging_tools as kt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
from matplotlib.patches import Path, PathPatch
import pandas as pd
from osgeo import gdal 

def load_data():
    df = pd.read_csv(r"File")
    return(df)

def get_data(df):
    return {
        "lons": df['Longitude'],
        "lats": df['Latitude'],
        "values": df['O18'],
    }

def extend_data(data):
    return {
        "lons": np.concatenate([np.array([lon-360 for lon in data["lons"]]), data["lons"], np.array([lon+360 for lon in data["lons"]])]),
        "lats": np.concatenate([data["lats"], data["lats"], data["lats"]]),
        "values":  np.concatenate([data["values"], data["values"], data["values"]]),
    }

def generate_grid(data, basemap, delta=1):
    grid = {
        'lon': np.arange(-180, 180, delta),
        'lat': np.arange(np.amin(data["lats"]), np.amax(data["lats"]), delta)
    }
    grid["x"], grid["y"] = np.meshgrid(grid["lon"], grid["lat"])
    grid["x"], grid["y"] = basemap(grid["x"], grid["y"])
    return grid

def interpolate(data, grid):
    uk = UniversalKriging(
        data["lons"],
        data["lats"],
        data["values"],
        variogram_model='exponential',
        verbose=True,
        drift_terms=["functional"],
        functional_drift=[func],
    )
    return uk.execute("grid", grid["lon"], grid["lat"])

def prepare_map_plot():
    figure, axes = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
    basemap = Basemap(projection='robin', lon_0=0, lat_0=0, resolution='h',area_thresh=1000,ax=axes) 
    return figure, axes, basemap

def plot_mesh_data(interpolation, grid, basemap):
    colormesh = basemap.contourf(grid["x"], grid["y"], interpolation,32, cmap='RdBu_r') #plot the data on the map. plt.cm.RdYlBu_r
    color_bar = basemap.colorbar(colormesh,location='bottom',pad="10%") 


df = load_data()
base_data = get_data(df)
figure, axes, basemap = prepare_map_plot()
grid = generate_grid(base_data, basemap, 90)
extended_data = extend_data(base_data)
interpolation, interpolation_error = interpolate(extended_data, grid)
plot_mesh_data(interpolation, grid,basemap)
plt.show()
```

I now only use universal kriging and create these images:

[image]

I get the expected error: `ValueError: Must specify location(s) and strength(s) of point drift terms.`

I just know that I have to create a grid with the height, but I don't know how and I don't know how to make the drift dependent on the altitude. The altitude formula is:

[image: -0.2 (O18)/100 m(altitude)]

where 100 m represents 100 m hight difference.

The interesting thing is that there is this website with examples: however, I am too inexperienced in coding to understand the examples and to transfer them to my example: https://python.hotexamples.com/examples/core/-/calc_cR/python-calc_cr-function-examples.html

conclusion:
I don't know how to define the ["external_drift"] to do what I want (this is based on me being so inexperienced in coding in general).

I've been trying to solve these problems for 3 weeks now, but I'm really getting nowhere.

Comment: I don't know that library or that branch of math, but are you sure this is ok? `drift_terms=["point_log"]`

Comment: I see the edit, but the point is: are you sure you're not forgetting to tell it's `data["external_drift"]` and not just `["external_drift"]`?

Comment: @user_ I know, cause I don´t Know how to define the ["external_drift"]

Comment: @user_ so I write it down clearly

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245718/discussion-between-weiss-and-user).

Comment: @user_ can you pleas have anouther look at my problem, cause I don´t understand akoois answers :-e

Comment: In relation to my previous comment: `drift_terms=["functional"]` is legit. `drift_terms` [accepts](https://buildmedia.readthedocs.org/media/pdf/pykrige/latest/pykrige.pdf) a list of strings.

Comment: @user_ how does a list of strings look like? I have no Idea :-e

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation of pykrige.uk.UniversalKriging (https://geostat-framework.readthedocs.io/projects/pykrige/en/stable/generated/pykrige.uk.UniversalKriging.html#pykrige.uk.UniversalKriging):

> drift_terms (list of strings, optional) – List of drift terms to
> include in universal kriging. Supported drift terms are currently
> ‘regional_linear’, ‘point_log’, ‘external_Z’, ‘specified’, and
> ‘functional’.

In your code you specified drift_terms = ["external_drift"] which is not supported. I'm sorry I don't have specialized knowledge in this model so I cannot help you much further. But it's very likely these are the parameters that you need to specify:

> external_drift (array_like, optional) – Gridded data used for the
> external Z scalar drift term. Must be shape (M, N), where M is in the
> y-direction and N is in the x-direction. Grid spacing does not need to
> be constant. If grid spacing is not constant, must specify the grid
> cell sizes. If the problem involves anisotropy, the external drift
> values are extracted based on the pre-adjusted coordinates (i.e., the
> original coordinate system).
>
> external_drift_x (array_like, optional) – X-coordinates for gridded
> external Z-scalar data. Must be shape (M,) or (M, 1), where M is the
> number of grid cells in the x-direction. The coordinate is treated as
> the center of the cell.
>
> external_drift_y (array_like, optional) – Y-coordinates for gridded
> external Z-scalar data. Must be shape (N,) or (N, 1), where N is the
> number of grid cells in the y-direction. The coordinate is treated as
> the center of the cell.

Comment: Hi, thank you, I am aware that something is missing. I have also written this. I also know the documentation very well but it doesn't help me.

Comment: If so please update your question and include your new error so people can help you better.

Comment: It would also be easier to help you if you include your error trace, which states the error line, error code, etc.

Comment: See my conclusion text I hope it is clear! If not write me please 

Comment: As I answered, the way you specify the argument drift_terms in your interpolate function is wrong. drift_terms requires a list of string, which are only allowed to contains ‘regional_linear’, ‘point_log’, ‘external_Z’, ‘specified’, and ‘functional’. You specify ["external_drift"] which is not allowed

Comment: I also suggested three other parameters for UniversalKriging() that may help you defining external_drift thing. Please try that to see if it fixes your problem

Comment: Hi @akooi Ok, I have changed that now! But I am now unsure how to define the function [func] so that it works with the height.

Comment: And I don't quite understand what you mean by the other three parameters!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/245725/discussion-between-weiss-and-akooi).

Comment: Hi @akooi I have now looked at this again for a few hours, but still can't come up with an idea how to generate the list of strigs. Do you have an example?

Comment: What do you mean you don't understand the three other parameters?. I thought you just need to include external_drift, external_drift_x, and external_drift_y into your interpolate function? Are you having trouble with Python or the math?, If it's the latter I cannot help you because I don't have specialized knowledge in your area.

Comment: I have mainly trouble with python .-e

Comment: Please tell me what parts you don't understand so we can further this conversation. You don't know what "list" are or don't understand what "array-like" or what?. Btw, your interpolate function requires 2 parameters, "data" and "grid", what is the data type of this "grid"?

Comment: data are the base_data

Comment: I don´t understand, whatshould be written in this list!

Answer (score 0):

The error 'ValueError: Must specify location(s) and strength(s) of point drift terms.' seems to only prompt if you have chosen 'point_log' as drift_terms

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33079124)